# why can't gsutil find the python executable in powershell?

Tags: gcloud, gsutil

So I installed the Google Cloud SDK on Windows 10 and gsutil can't seem to find/see the python executable:

```
~> gsutil help cp
ERROR: (gsutil) "C:\Python38\python.exe": command not found
~>
```

The executable is in *exactly* that place and works fine:

```
~> where.exe python
C:\Python38\python.exe
C:\Users\omort\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
~>
```

The second python exe is the link that opens the python page in the MS Store - is that screwing things up? Any suggestions?

Note that I did *not* install the "bundled python" option in the SDK installer since I already have python installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your CLOUDSDK_PYTHON env variable is not set correctly. I would recommend you to set correctly the env variable executing something like the below

```
set CLOUDSDK_PYTHON="C:\Python38\python.exe"
```

Or in case you want to set permanently use the below command

```
setx CLOUDSDK_PYTHON="C:\Python38\python.exe"
```

Comment: Sweet - thanks. Not sure why that wasn't set during install, but hey - it works!

Comment: at least on my Windows 10 PC, the syntax for `setx` does not include `=` e.g. it should be `setx CLOUDSDK_PYTHON "C:\Python38\python.exe"`

Answer (score 0):

I've run set below using PowerShell. **/M** Specifies that the variable should be set in the **system variables** wide.

```
setx /M CLOUDSDK_PYTHON "C:\Python27\python.exe"
```